# DynamicPartition returns single output instead of multiple

Tags: java, tensorflow

Here is my code which constructs graph using DynamicPartition operation to split a vector [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] by two vectors [1, 2, 3] and [4, 5, 6] using mask [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]:

```
@Test
public void dynamicPartition2() {
    Graph graph = new Graph();

    Output a = graph.opBuilder("Const", "a")
            .setAttr("dtype", DataType.INT64)
            .setAttr("value", Tensor.create(new long[]{6}, LongBuffer.wrap(new long[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6})))
            .build().output(0);

    Output partitions = graph.opBuilder("Const", "partitions")
            .setAttr("dtype", DataType.INT32)
            .setAttr("value", Tensor.create(new long[]{6}, IntBuffer.wrap(new int[] {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0})))
            .build().output(0);

    graph.opBuilder("DynamicPartition", "result")
            .addInput(a)
            .addInput(partitions)
            .setAttr("num_partitions", 2)
            .build().output(0);

    try (Session s = new Session(graph)) {
        List<Tensor> outputs = s.runner().fetch("result").run();

        try (Tensor output = outputs.get(0)) {
            LongBuffer result = LongBuffer.allocate(3);
            output.writeTo(result);

            assertArrayEquals("Shape", new long[]{3}, output.shape());
            assertArrayEquals("Values", new long[]{4, 5, 6}, result.array());
        }

        //Test will fail here
        try (Tensor output = outputs.get(1)) {
            LongBuffer result = LongBuffer.allocate(3);
            output.writeTo(result);

            assertArrayEquals("Shape", new long[]{3}, output.shape());
            assertArrayEquals("Values", new long[]{1, 2, 3}, result.array());
        }
    }
}
```

After calling `s.runner().fetch("result").run()` List of length 1 is returned with value [4, 5, 6]. It seems that my graph produces only one output.

How to obtain the rest part of splitted vector?

Comment: Do you need it only for java or will python answer be enough?

Comment: Any answers are welcome

Comment: has my answer explained anything?

Comment: Your example returns two tesors, that is excatly what I expect from my Java program. The problem is that my program returns single tensor.

Comment: If you do exactly this, maybe it is time to file a bug in TF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DynamicPartition` operation returns multiple outputs (one for each partition), but the [`Session.Runner.fetch`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/java/reference/org/tensorflow/Session.Runner.html#fetch(java.lang.String)) call is only requesting the 0-th output.

The Java API lacks a bunch of convenience sugar that the Python API has, but you can do what you want by explicitly requesting all the outputs. In other words, change from:

```
List<Tensor> outputs = s.runner().fetch("result").run();
```

to

```
List<Tensor> outputs = s.runner().fetch("result", 0).fetch("result", 1).run();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that is the solution

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about java (I do not know it and do not have environment to investigate), but in python everything works correctly. For example this

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
b = tf.constant([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])
c = tf.dynamic_partition(a, b, 2)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    v1, v2 = sess.run(c)
    print v1
    print v2
```

returns you correct partitions.